# DataTables, jQuery, hiding column

Tags: jquery, properties, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I have a "small" problem with hiding column in DataTable using code like below:

```
var XTable = $('#table1').DataTable();
    XTable.column(0).visible( false );
```

First column is hiden but editors association for others columns move to the next ones.
I mean ie. i set datepicker for editing 3rd column but after hiding datepicker appears if I edit 4th column.
How to avoid this problem?

Comment: I suspect this to be same misbehaviour / missing functionality as this -> http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/22385/bug-report-1-10-x-first-icon-visible-even-if-sorting-is-turned-off#latest but cant really say, have not worked with the Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know you'll be hiding it in advance, it is probably optimal to hide it in your DataTable definition rather than after the fact. See: http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

```
var XTable = $('#table1').DataTable({
                  "columnDefs": [
                    {
                       "targets": [0],
                       "visible": false,
                    }
                 ]
              });
```

Comment: Thank you, but I use in code:    aoColumns': [{type: 'select', data: "{'O1':'O1','O2':'O2'} , submit: 'Ok', cancel: 'Cancel', visible: 'false'}....    but this doesn't work:(

Comment: @Artik depends on version of plugin, API went through major changes for version 1.10

Comment: @charlietfl - i use DataTables 1.10.3

Comment: @Artik then this answer is correct approach per the docs. `aoColumns` is now just `columns` I believe although some of the API has backward compatibility with older property conventions. Create a simple demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I saw somewhere information about a similar issue, ie. if working with the visibility of columns when using datatable.makeEditable. Unfortunately, I can not find again this thread. Thank you all for your help.